# Error in Springboot getting property name instead of the value

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm new in Spring-Boot and I development a Api-Rest application. I have a problem with my application.properties when I run my app this get the property name instead of the property value.

**I´m usig Spring-Boot 2.64
**

1. My application.properties it's located in src/main/resources and I declare my property inside:

```
app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh=10
```

2. I try to get the value using the annotation @Value in the @RestController class like this

```
@Value("${app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh}")
private String requestRefreshStatusValue;
```

3. I need to declare the properties file in the code using the annotation @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") in the class @Configuration because if not I get a exception.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan({ "com.apirestapp.web" })
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

```
ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'restConfigController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh' in value "${app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:405)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4851)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh' in value "${app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh}"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:180)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:210)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.lambda$processProperties$0(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveEmbeddedValue(AbstractBeanFactory.java:936)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

4. After declare i can see this messages in the console log

```
DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh]
DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh] not found - trying original name [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh].
DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh]
DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh] threw NamingException with message: Name [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh].. Returning null.
DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh' in PropertySource 'class path resource [application.properties]' with value of type String
DEBUG org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'app.rest.params.requestStatus.refresh' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
```

This problem happens whith all properties that I add in the application.porperties file (whith the log configuration properties, with the datasource configuration properties, etc. Can anyone helps me?

Thaks you so much!

I expect get the value of my properties but I failed in this becasue I only can get my properties name.

Comment: Work with the framework not around/against it. Remove the `@PropertySource`, remove the `@EnableWebMvc` and `@ComponentScan`. Those shouldn't be needed in a spring boot application.

Comment: If you need to declare the `@PropertySource` due to an error you aren't initializing your application properly. You are using an `@SpringBootApplication` and the `SpringApplication.run` within a `main` method?

Comment: @M. Deinum thanks for your answer. I have an a SpringBootApplication class with a main metoh

`@SpringBootApplication()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.apirestapp" )
public class MyApiRestApp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(MyApiRestApp.class, args);
 }
}`

I using `@EnableWebMvc` beacasue I´m implements WebMvcConfigurer and I see in a documentation thats it´s necesary, maybe I´m wrong. And the `@PropertySource` it´s because if not I get the error I explain this in the step 3 of my pricipal post.

Comment: You are wrong. Don't use `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables large parts of the auto configuration. You don't need to component scan either. All what you are doing feels like you are trying hard to work around the framework/tools you are using instead of using them.